# need to write Matlab code to solve below equation

Tags: matlab

```
a1 * sqrt(abs(b1-x)) + ...
a2 * sqrt(abs(b2-x)) + ...
a3 * sqrt(abs(b3-x)) + ...
a4 * sqrt(abs(b4-x)) = 0
```

need to find `x` when all variables are known.

I tried with `solve` but it said

> Explicit solution could not be found. In solve at 160

I am new to MATLAB, trying to analyze wind tunnel data.

Comment: have a look at the `fzero` function

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a question and answer site for all problems related to coding. Generally, questions like these are not very well received, because to be honest, you could have found the answer to this by reading the MATLAB documentation about root finding, searching for zero finding on MATLAB Central, etc. Stack Overflow is not a coding service -- but that is basically what you're asking us to do here. For any future questions you may have, please show what you have tried so far, that you have at least googled and tried a few techniques, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the values of those constants, there may anywhere between 0 and 8 possible solutions. Keep that in mind.

To get you started:

```
% a = 4 × 1
% b = 4 × 1
function x_root = find_zero(a, b, x_initial_guess)

    x_root = fzero(@(x) a(:).' * sqrt(abs(b(:) - x)),...
                   x_initial_guess);

end
```

Example usage

```
> find_zero(randn(4,1), randn(4,1), 0)
ans =
    3.445614467672894e-002
```